# int array vs. char array

Tags: java, methods, casting, signature

I have my code like this:

```
public void execute(char[] array) {
    mergesort(array,0,array.length);
}
```

But here's the signature of `mergesort(int[] data, int first, int n)`

So I can't apply mergesort on my char array.
Any solution to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the `char[]` to a `new int[]` and copy back when you have finished.

Or you can copy the code for mergesort and change it to take a `char[]`

Answer (score 2):

Three possibilities:

1. Change `mergesort()` to take `char[]`.
2. Create an `int` array with the same contents as the `char` array, and sort that, copying the results back.
3. Use [`Arrays.sort(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char%5B%5D%29).